# Selenium, XPATH to search for an Element in a table and Click on Radio button

Tags: selenium, xpath

I need to select an Item from the list of Table entries and click on Radio button. Radio button is on the left.
In the HTML Code below 
Only Unique ID to look for a selection is the "TestSucscription"
I need to grep for this Value in the Table(It can have multiple Rows and It can be in any position) and then click on the Radio button on to its left.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="" type="radio" value="2ba068ff-b797-444e-b56b-a0ae0ae06f06" name="subscription[id]">
        <div class="hide"></div>
    </td>
    <td> TestSubscription</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Testing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="" type="radio" value="36a87684-9a65-4455-8605-dc5b5368fc23" name="subscription[id]">
        <div class="hide">
            <span class="error error-msg">This cannot be left blank.</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>SecurityProtection</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>CPN ChildProtection CPN ChildProtection</td>
</tr>
```

Please help me with this. I have tried below options in Webdriver(Java)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'TestSubscription')]]/td/input[@type='radio']")).click();
```

I think Im going down the tree and coming back to click on Radio button which is why Its failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the radio button with the following xpath:

```
//td[contains(text(), 'TestSubscription')]/../td/input
```

This matches the `td` with the text, goes up to the parent, then traverses to the `input` control you want to click.

Comment: Thank you @Richard :) Its working. I missed to go back to the Parent.

Comment: @user3693276 You should be able to accept this answer, if it works for you.